# Jqgrid show errors from json

Tags: php, jquery, json, oracle, jqgrid

My problem is this, I want to show errors through the information I get the json. That is, when we added / edited in jgrid something we always expect to get a response in json data. Then I remembered what it was, if you can not add something, I send in the json error.

I wanted to show the error using the Highlight / Error in Jquery. And therein lies my problem, how do I show it. From what I've been searching, should be the attribute aftersubmit implement and handle the response here but just that I am not getting.

Code:

```
afterSubmit: function (response) 
{
   if(responce == false)
        alert("test");
}
```

Format error in json:

```
{"Response":false,"Message":"Dados inválidos"}
```

Someone can help me?

---------------------------------------- **SOLUTION** ------------------------------------------------------

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, 
    {
        reloadAfterSubmit:false,
        afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) 
        {
            if(jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText).Response  == false)
            {
                alert(jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText).Message);
                return [false,null,null];
            }
            else
            {
                return [true,null,null];
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) 
{

  if(jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText).Response)
alert(jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText).Message);

}
```

Comment: By chance I had used it, and still does not appear anything. I had a better look and found that I had to put in jqgrid reloadaftersubmit: false.

And besides continuing to do when I add reload continues without showing any alert. Already beginning to despair with this

Comment: What do you see in the firebug console ?

Comment: Say what you've said here. Post get a json format with the error that I mentioned, which appears yet another Get everything that appears in the table

Comment: Are you using inlineEdit ?

Comment: Updated the answer please try it, afterSubmit had 2 parameters response and postdata

Comment: I've found part of the problem. If you put the aftersubmit properties of jqgrid does not work, but if you put common jqgrid.extend already works, half part. That is, following your response if you take the if, it now shows the error does not appear if I put anything.

Comment: I got it, I put the solution in my question. From already thank you very much for the attention you gave me ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think for the error, just return the error as a string from the AJAX script.  The JqGrid is expecting to get JSON data, but when it receives a string, it will display the error for you.

I use JqGrid with XML instead of JSON, but in my AJAX script, when I have an error, I just return a string instead of the XML that jqgrid is expecting, and the grid displays the error message correctly.

Please try this afterSubmit code and see if you see anything:

```
afterSubmit: function (response) 
{
   alert(response);
}
```

If you can see that, then you are all set, you just need to tweak the function to only display the response when there is actually an error.

Comment: I realize what you mean but I still have difficulty in showing this error, even from a string

Comment: Also you spelled "response" wrong: `if(responce == false)` should be `if(response == false)`, also another idea, check the answer.